# Adding Mobile Home Door to Horiz Aluminum Siding wall. How to seal?

Tags: doors, installation

I have a Smithbilt shed which has horizontal aluminum siding for walls, with 2x4 framing inside. I have a shutter door and want to add a normal entry door (so I can close the door without being locked in) to convert to a woodworking workshop.

A mobile home door works best (the manufacturer fits mobile home doors as extras, but this shed came with the home purchase).

Framing to house the door is not an issue, but concerned about how to weatherproof the siding against the aluminum extruded door frame. (Normally the door frame would be behind the siding).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Metal to metal **Butyl Rubber Caulk** is the traditional sealant of choice, as it never fully hardens, so it's not torn apart by thermal cycling as caulks that set/cure solid are. It can be a moderate pain to find these days

(*i.e.* I do get results that are the right stuff when searching, but evidently folks that want to sell unsuitable silicone rubber caulking by underhanded means have "bought spots" in search results for butyl rubber caulk so that the first 6 results I got were utterly the wrong product. Silicone has places where it's the right product, and this isn't one of them.)

Butyl flashing tape may also suit your needs.